# For Rails, why does it matter that the Gem Devise is Rack-based?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rack

As far as I know, Rack just sits in between Rails and the Webserver (like Mongrel or Webrick), to act as an "adapter" so that the choice of webserver is not important.

So why does [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is known to be Rack-based and it is good?  If Rack is transparent, doesn't it not matter whether the authentication system is Rack based or non-Rack based? (or how does it relate to Rack at all?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It just means that the gem does not depend on a particular implementation (such as Rails) of the Rack interface, just that it conforms to it. This is good because you can use the gem with other Rack-based frameworks such as Sinatra.

Comment: does that mean Devise is Rack and Web server agnostic, like Active Record is DBMS agnostic?  Or does it mean it uses Rack - essentially it means Devise uses Web Server Gateway Interface (WSGI)...  so Devise cannot be used with Rails app such as 2.2 or 2.3 when it is not Rack based? (you have to make the Rails 2.x app Rack based before you can use Devise?)

Comment: Devise depends on a Ruby web framework that implements the Rack interface, so Devise is _not_ Rack agnostic (but it is agnostic of the _implementation_ of the Rack interface). Since Rails 2.x is not Rack-based, you cannot use the current version of Devise. You can however use an older version of Devise from the v1 branch.